# How to download multiple file list get from controller ? MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, file, download

I am passing list of files from controller to client. but is is not downloading list of files getting from controller. If i return one file it works ok.

js code for calling controller method,

```
window.open(utilitiesService.getFullPath() + '/Survey/AllRecord);
```

Controller returning list of FileResult from controller like,

```
     public List<FileResult> AllRecord()
            {
     List<FileResult> FileList = new List<FileResult>();
                    FileResult res =null;
                    foreach (var oParam in result)
                    {
                        int VisitId = Convert.ToInt32(oParam.Id);
                        res = PrintSurveyDetailsReport(VisitId);
                        FileList.Add(res);
                        res = null;  
                    }
                    return FileList;
}
```

I got error while returning list of files that is,

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.FileResult]
```

How to download all files in list one by one

Hope for your suggestion

Comment: You can make a zip of all files and download that zip file.

Comment: i am looking for this